# select value in detail view controller table view based on bool value in app delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an entity/class in my application that is populated with a JSON call.  Once this call is made I set some values in my application delegate that don't change often by iterating through this entity.  All of that works just great, just giving the back story....  Once the user clicks on an item in my table view I want to take the string value I have assigned to either 0 for false or 1 for true and use that as the index for the selected value in the detail screens table view which is a "No" and then a "Yes" each in their own cells.  Basically I am trying to show the user what the current setting is and if they want to change it I will allow the user to change their selection and save that back to the previous page's table view along with an update to my entity.

The problem I am having is the detail screen's table view is not selecting BOTH rows, not just the selected index.  I need to fix just this first please.

cellForRowAtIndexPath - seems to be working correctly...

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *result = nil;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

result = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (result == nil){
    result = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Settings *settings = (Settings *)[appDelegate.settings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Save the value the user clicked on for use in updating the MasterViewController and the data model
result.textLabel.text = settings.name;

NSLog(@"result.textLabel.text: %@", result.textLabel.text);

return result;
}
```

This is where things get ugly!

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSLog(@"appDelegate.selectedValueInSettingsCheckedIndexValue: %i", (int)appDelegate.selectedValueInSettingsCheckedIndexValue);

NSLog(@"appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value: %@", appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value == @"No" ? @"0" : @"1");

if(appDelegate.selected_category == FROZEN && appDelegate.selected_setting == QUANTITY && [appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value isEqualToString:ZERO]) {

    NSLog(@"Reached frozen quantity with value of: %@", appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value == @"No" ? @"0" : @"1");
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %i", indexPath.row);

    if ((int)appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value == (int)appDelegate.selectedValueInSettingsCheckedIndexValue)/*(int)[appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value isEqualToString:@"No"] ? @"0" : @"1")*/ {
            [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
            [self performSelector:@selector(unselectCellAtIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            [cell setSelected:NO];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
} else if (appDelegate.selected_category == FROZEN && appDelegate.selected_setting == FACINGS) {

    NSLog(@"Reached vegetables facings with value of: %@", appDelegate.vegetables_facing_value == @"No" ? @"0" : @"1");
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %i", indexPath.row);
}
}
```

more updated code...

```
-(void)unselectCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I realize this is a hellacious mess...I just need some direction.

Here is what my UI look like for the Main and Detail screens...

[image: Main]
[image: Detail...notice BOTH items are checked...]

Comment: You have: "if (true)". True is always true, so the if part of the if-else is always going to run.

Comment: Yes, I know this rdelmar.  I had different conditions there before.  Either way what I am getting is BOTh rows in my detail controller being checked. Any ideas on how I can refactor my code to fix this?

Comment: I have just updated my cellForRowAtIndexPath function to avoid any confusion with the "true" condition I set before.  I know there has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what the 2 rows with No and Yes mean. Given the example you posted, what should those 2 rows look like? I assume that you only want one to have a check mark, but are the No and YES correct?

Comment: @rdelmar, the "No" and "Yes" values are correct and from a separate array to populate the table view in the second screen.  I have the first page of the application updating from my Setting object with the correct Yes/No values shown in the detail label of the table on the first screen.  When I click on an item in that first screen I push the second view controller on to the screen.  I want the value seen in the first screen, for example: Salads - Facings with a value of "Yes" in the right label to be the selected or checked item in the second view controller.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following test project to do what I think you're trying to do, but using my own design that I think simplifies things a little, and seems to work fine. The design was as follows:

1) Apple doesn't recommend getting data for a table view from a singleton like the app delegate, so the only thing I do in that class is set up the root view controller for the window:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    TableController *tc = [[TableController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableController" bundle:nil];
    tc.title = @"Main Table";
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tc];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

2) I created a class, DownloadFromServer, that would do the downloading, parsing of the JSON, creation of the Setting objects and the array to hold them. It then posts a notification with the array of data. The class, as it stands now, just simulates the data since I don't have access to your server. I call the method to start downloading (simulated) from the table view controller.

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading { //:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.settings = [NSMutableArray array];
    //NSError *error = nil;
    //id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //Simulated data here 
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    [result addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@2377,@"CatalogID",@"Frozen",@"Category",@"0",@"Facings",@"25",@"ID",@"0",@"Quantity", nil]];
    [result addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@2377,@"CatalogID",@"Fruit",@"Category",@"0",@"Facings",@"19",@"ID",@"0",@"Quantity", nil]];
    [result addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@2377,@"CatalogID",@"Salads",@"Category",@"1",@"Facings",@"12",@"ID",@"1",@"Quantity", nil]];
    [result addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@2377,@"CatalogID",@"Vegetables",@"Category",@"1",@"Facings",@"26",@"ID",@"0",@"Quantity", nil]];

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        for (NSDictionary *item in result) {

            NSString *settingsID = [item objectForKey:@"ID"];
            NSString *category = [item objectForKey:@"Category"];
            NSString *categoryID = [item objectForKey:@"CatalogID"];
            NSString *facings = [item objectForKey:@"Facings"];
            NSString *quantity = [item objectForKey:@"Quantity"];

            Setting *setting = [[Setting alloc] initWithName:settingsID desc:category CategoryID:categoryID Facings:facings Quantity:quantity];

            [self.settings addObject:setting]; 
        } 
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateReceived" object:self userInfo:@{@"array" : self.settings}];
}
```

3) The table view controller starts the download and the populates its local array from the data sent in the notification. In the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method I decided that the best way for the details table to modify the selection was to pass the setting object as well as the indexPath of the selected row -- this gives the DetailViewController all the info it needs to modify the data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateArray:) name:@"UpdateReceived" object:nil];
    DownloadFromServer *downloader = [[DownloadFromServer alloc]init];
    [downloader connectionDidFinishLoading];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)updateArray:(NSNotification *) aNote {
    self.theData = [aNote.userInfo valueForKey:@"array"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.theData.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.theData objectAtIndex:section] category];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Facings";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] facings]] intValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Quantity";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] quantity]] intValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    detailViewController.settingObject = [self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In the DetailViewController, I made it so the user can edit the NO/YES value by selecting a row in the table -- based on which row was selected, and which row was selected in the main table, the logic updates the value and reloads the table. When you hit the back button, the main table is also updated through the viewDidAppear method.

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Setting.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (self.selectedIndexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Facings", self.settingObject.category];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Quantity", self.settingObject.category];
            break;
        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    int isYes = (self.selectedIndexPath.row ?  self.settingObject.quantity.intValue : self.settingObject.facings.intValue);
    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"NO";
        cell.accessoryType = (isYes) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryNone : UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"YES";
        cell.accessoryType = (isYes) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int test = indexPath.row + (2 * self.selectedIndexPath.row);
    switch (test) {
        case 0:
            self.settingObject.facings = @"0";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.settingObject.facings = @"1";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.settingObject.quantity = @"0";
            break;
        case 3:
            self.settingObject.quantity = @"1";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're doing, but this line:

```
if ((int)indexPath.row == (int)[appDelegate.frozen_quantity_value isEqualToString:@"No"] ? @"0" : @"1")
```

will always evaluate to "true", because the ternary operator will return a string of "0" or "1", but a string is a valid object, so it will evaluate to true. This may not be your problem, but I really can't tell what you're trying to do with that piece of code -- for instance, what is unselectCellAtIndexPath:withObject:? You don't show the code for that.

Comment: I know it's a bit of a mess, I totally agree with you.  I updated the code above so you can see that method.  It's not really important to this issue, it exists so that when I select a row I don't have the blue highlight.  It's just a quick flash.  I added the code.  First off, does it make sense what I am trying to do from my explanation above?

Comment: I know why this is running twice for each row I click on.  I am trying to figure out a third variable for my Yes/No value that I can check against so as to select the correct row in the detail grid.  I'll update some more code, in an effort to be more clear.  I don't think it will work though.

Comment: Additionally, the problem I think lies in the fact that I don't really care what row was clicked on in the main screen with respect to indexPath.  What I am trying to do is take the value displayed in that detail label on the right of each row and set THAT string value as the selected or checked value in the detail screen.

Comment: In general, you should be getting the value of the No or YES in your main table view from the data source that populates that table. Then you need to pass that value to your details controller when you push it. If that value is a string of "0" or "1" (or No or YES), you should convert it to an int if you're using it in an if statement. I have to admit though, that I still don't understand what info you're trying to convey in your detail table -- it seems like the No or YES in the main table already tells you the same thing that having the NO or YES row selected in the detail table tells you.

Comment: I get that.  Can you direct me on how to make the way I am doing it work?

Comment: I edited my comment, to indicate my confusion. I don't know if I can help if I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: btw, I AM getting that yes/no value from my data source.  I want to allow the user to change that value from the detail screen.  For example, salads - facings has a value of Yes and I want that value, which is shown in the first screen to be checked in the second screen.  Next the user can change this value in the second screen and I will update my model.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, but can't you edit it from the first table. It still seems like the second table doesn't tell you anything that you can't get from the first.

Comment: It's meant to work quite similar to Settings on the iPhone when you select a Wi-Fi network.  If you have one already selected it shows up in the detail label in the table view.  You can drill-down to the next screen where that same network is checked and if you choose you can select a different one.  That's exactly the functionality I am trying to get.

Comment: The second table will allow the user to CHANGE the value.

Comment: The user cannot edit any values from the first table.  It's only for display.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17947/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-brianhevans)

Comment: @brianhevans, I made a test project that I think does what you want. I can either post it or rejoin our discussion and describe it there.

Comment: > this is above and beyond...I am going to pour through this in detail and see what I end up with.  I like the approach you used and I think it will work.  I'll be in touch tomorrow afternoon.  Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @brianhevans, I can send you a copy of the project if you'd like -- email me, at rdelmar@comcast.net if you want it. I find code much easier to study in an editor with all the right colors and spacings.